# How does KubeConfig file is used?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubeconfig

When we setup a kubernetes master using kubeadm init . At the end of the procedure we have to copy the /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf to $home/.kube/config .

When I opened the file , I found the below details .

- certificate authority data
- client certificate data
- client key data

I am aware the file is used for authentication when we try to access cluster using kubectl .

What I am trying to understand is from where these details are generated ? .

Comment: How you got your client cert/key depends on how you provisioned your cluster. In this case it's kubeadm giving these client certs to you.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options
- Use the automatically generated certificates if you have installed k8s with kubeadm
- Create your own certificates.

Once you have the certificates, you can follow these steps to manually configure them
https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/certificates/#configure-certificates-manually
To create your own CA certificates, there are many google links and here is one for your reference.
http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~zmiller/ca-howto/
If you are new to this, I would suggest you start with "A Single-level CA"